# .NET Standard 2 Base NuGet Package shows error for no apparent reason

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package, .net-standard-2.0

Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.2) on Windows using .NET Standard 2.0.3 project.

The Dependencies node shows an exclamation because the NuGet base node is showing Exclamation in VS but none of the NuGet packages are showing an exclamation!

Do you know how to sort this out? I have just created this project from scratch while converting from PCL.

N.B. The project compiles as expected, this is a cosmetic problem.

[image: NuGet packages node with exclamation]

Comment: so what is the warning in the errors window? Does the output window show anything for nuget?

Comment: You are right, the warning message is there. Silly me, thank you

Comment: @Adam, please share the warning message here.

Comment: I have this after updating packages. simply closing/reopen project solves it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 whenever there is something that I can't explain, I close and open, so already done.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I sorted it out, the warning was in the Output

Comment: @Adam, So, what is the  warning message? I can not see it in your question. You should share it in your question. If you have resolve this issue, you can share your solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the reason for the exclamation was not showing in the solution panel. The error was in the "Output" window in Visual Studio.
In my specific case, one of the referenced NuGets was not compatible with .NET Standards 2, but the NuGet itself did not show any warning in the solution explorer, however, if you've expanded it you will see a warning.